# Cheap PSTN Card with caller Id for Asterisk Linux server

Tags: asterisk, pstn

For my house I just wanted to setup a caller Id system that would auto-reply on certain callers to avoid harements. Any sugestion for this?

I'm thinking on a Linux + Asterisk + PSTN Card with caller Id and configure asterisk to handle these calls, I need to be able to answer some of the calls on the normal phone so this would just be work a bit like an IDS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this belongs to SF but you could get most modems using Intel 537P (AKA Ambient MD3200 ) chipset to be recognized as `Digium Wildcard X100P` clone by Asterisk. Do not confuse it with Intel 537EP (newer but unsupported chip).

- 537P is rectangular chip

[image]

- 537EP is square 64-pin TQFP

[image]

Also pay attention to which version `G`(global) or `U`(USA) you get.

Comment: Cool, just found out that in Brasil the Caller Id is paid monthly to a operator...